# Gettting "Class not found" error for many jars that I have included in classpath in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, classpath, netbeans-7

I am trying to create a Java web app project in Netbeans that uses many external JAR files.

I have created a `lib` folder and put all the JAR files there and I've added those Jar files to the build path. However I am still getting `Package XYZ does not exist` error in Netbeans.

What am I doing wrong here? How can i resolve this error? Is there some way to verify if my JARs are included or not?

Comment: Are your jars appearing in the `Libraries` node of the `Projects` window?

Comment: @madth3 yes they are appearing there...

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project and goto Source/Binary fromat >> Select a lower version of JDK if you have selected a higher version already. Else try choosing other version see if that makes a difference.